# SCTP ordered message delivery

Tags: c, packet, sctp, partial-ordering

Is it possible to force *SCTP* to send all data completely ordered?

Let's do this experiment:

1) Take this [SCTP-discard-server](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/blob/master/programs/discard_server.c) and this [SCTP-client](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/blob/master/programs/client.c).

2) Let the client count to 100 a lot of times and send a byte each time respectively to the server.

```
for(long i=0; i< 1000000000; i++){
    char temp = (char)(i%100) + 1;
    usrsctp_sendv(
        sock, (void *)&temp, 1,
        NULL, 0, NULL, 0, SCTP_SENDV_NOINFO, 0
    );
}
```

3) Let the server count along the same way and compare its number with the received one.

```
printf("%d %d\n", (int)buffer[0], (int)(test));
if ((int)test != (int)buffer[0]) break;
```

Some seconds later:

```
66 66
67 67
68 68
69 69
51 70
```

Voila!

I compiled this with `$ gcc discard_server.c -Wall -lusrsctp` using *gcc7.3.0* on my *Ubuntu 18.04* machine. And yes, I have already tried disabling every kind of nagel-algorithms via `SCTP_NODELAY`.

What did I miss? Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that `usrsctp_sendv(..)` can fail, if the socket buffer is full for example. This is what happened.

I tried `while(usrsctp_sendv(..) < 0)` and now client and server count along the right way.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably missing is the fact that SCTP does not guarantee sequential delivery within association. Sequential delivery is guaranteed only within a stream.

As [RFC 4960 chapter 1.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#section-1.5.2) says:

> Internally, SCTP assigns a Stream Sequence Number to each
> message passed to it by the SCTP user.  On the receiving side, SCTP
> ensures that messages are delivered to the SCTP user in sequence
> within a given stream.  However, while one stream may be blocked
> waiting for the next in-sequence user message, delivery from other
> streams may proceed.

I guess you have more then one steam configured and the implementation that you using distributes the load between streams. This should be easy to confirm with wireshark trace.

If you carry about message order you should specify stream id when you send your data and check stream id when it arrives.